# BookshelfJS: How to apply BelongsToMany?

Tags: bookshelf.js

I am confused how to apply BelongsToMany with Bookshelf.

Say, there is a Movie that BelongsToMany Genres, e.g.

```
"The Artist" has the genres "Comedy, Drama"
```

I have setup a join table called `join_movies_genres` that has FK `movie_id` and `genre_id`.

I try to fetch genres from a Movie with and without a `through(...)` definition. I get however undefined targets, similar to:

```
relatedData:
 { type: 'belongsToMany',
   target:
   { [Function]
    NotFoundError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
    NoRowsUpdatedError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
    NoRowsDeletedError: [Function: ErrorCtor] },
 targetTableName: 'genres',
 targetIdAttribute: 'id',
 joinTableName: 'join_movies_genres',
 foreignKey: { debug: true },
 otherKey: undefined,
 parentId: 1,
 parentTableName: 'movies',
 parentIdAttribute: 'id',
 parentFk: 1,
 throughTarget:
  { [Function]
    NotFoundError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
    NoRowsUpdatedError: [Function: ErrorCtor],
    NoRowsDeletedError: [Function: ErrorCtor] },
 throughTableName: 'join_movies_genres',
 throughIdAttribute: 'id',
 throughForeignKey: { debug: true } }
```

So, how would I approach setting up this relation? How can I enable a debug output?

The current state of the Model is:

```
var Movie = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'movies',

    genres: function() {
      // return this.belongsToMany(Genre, 'join_movies_genres', 'movie_id', 'genre_id', {debug: true});
      // return this.belongsToMany(Genre).through(JoinMovieGenre, 'movie_id', 'genre_id');
      return this.belongsToMany(Genre, 'join_movies_genres', 'movie_id', 'genre_id').through(JoinMovieGenre, {debug: true});
    }
});

var Genre = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'genres'
});

new Movie({title: 'The Artist'}).fetch({debug: true}).then(function(m) {
  console.log(m.toJSON());
  console.log(m.genres())
})
```

A sandbox of this code is at https://github.com/mulderp/bookshelf-demo/tree/cli_migrations

Comment: Update: There are several things I just learned. Naming conventions makes it easier to retrieve relationships, and the fetch allows to customizie a query with options:  fetch({withRelated: ['genres'], require: true, debug: true}). - still need to explore this problem a bit more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work?

```
var Movie = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'movies',

    genres: function() {
      return this.belongsToMany(Genre, 'join_movies_genres', 'movie_id', 'genre_id');
    }
});

var Genre = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'genres'
});

new Movie({title: 'The Artist'}).fetch({withRelated:['genres']}).then(function(m) {
  console.log(m.toJSON());
});
```

Comment: I wrote a blog post about some of the experiments about this: http://thinkingonthinking.com/relations-with-bookshelfjs/ - was surprised that the attach() which works nicely on many-to-many does not on one-to-many ... why :) ?

Comment: It's simple: `attach` is a many-to-many exclusive method. From the official page: "*Attaches one or more ids from a foreign table to the current table, in a belongsToMany relationship.*"

Comment: thanks! OK, then, to attach a record from 1:N requires explicitly setting the foreign_key, e.g. movie.set('director_id', 1); ?